# Idiomatic React with heavy DOM manipulation (MathJax)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mathjax

I am using MathJax in a React application. MathJax brings a lot of complexity: it has its own system for managing concurrency, and makes changes to the DOM that React doesn't know about. This leads to a lot of DOM micromanaging which would generally be considered anti-patterns in React, and I'm wondering if my code can be made better.

In the code below, `MJX` is a component which takes a TeX string as input and feeds it into MathJax. `RenderGroup` is a convenience component which keeps track of when all its `MJX` descendants have finished typesetting.

```js
/// <reference types="mathjax" />
import * as React from "react";

/* Promise that resolves once MathJax is loaded and ready to go */
export const MathJaxReady = new Promise<typeof MathJax>((resolve, reject) => {
  const script = $("#js-async-mathjax");
  if (!script) return;

  if (window.hasOwnProperty("MathJax")) {
    MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End", resolve);
  } else {
    script.addEventListener("load", () => MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End", resolve));
  }
});

interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement> {
  display?: boolean;
}

export class MJX extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  private resolveReady: () => void;
  domElement: HTMLSpanElement;
  jax: MathJax.ElementJax;

  // Promise that resolves after initial typeset
  ready: Promise<void>;

  static defaultProps = {
    display: false
  }

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.ready = new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.resolveReady = resolve);

    this.Typeset = this.Typeset.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await MathJaxReady;

    this.Typeset()
    .then(() => this.jax = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax(this.domElement)[0])
    .then(this.resolveReady);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    /* original span has been eaten by MathJax, manage updates ourselves */
    const text = this.props.children instanceof Array ? this.props.children.join("") : this.props.children,
          nextText = nextProps.children instanceof Array ? nextProps.children.join("") : nextProps.children;

    // rerender?
    if (this.jax && text !== nextText) {
      this.jax.Text(nextProps.children);
    }

    // classes changed?
    if (this.props.className !== nextProps.className) {
      const classes = this.props.className ? this.props.className.split(" ") : [],
            newClasses = nextProps.className ? nextProps.className.split(" ") : [];

      const add = newClasses.filter(_ => !classes.includes(_)),
            remove = classes.filter(_ => !newClasses.includes(_));

      for (const _ of remove)
        this.domElement.classList.remove(_);
      for (const _ of add)
        this.domElement.classList.add(_);
    }

    // style attribute changed?
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props.style) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.style)) {
      Object.keys(this.props.style || {})
      .filter(_ => !(nextProps.style || {}).hasOwnProperty(_))
      .forEach(_ => this.props.style[_] = null);
      Object.assign(this.domElement.style, nextProps.style);
    }

    return false;
  }

  Typeset(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, this.domElement]);
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(resolve);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {children, display, ...attrs} = this.props;

    const [open, close] = display ? ["\\[", "\\]"] : ["\\(", "\\)"];

    return (
      <span {...attrs} ref={node => this.domElement = node}>{open + children + close}</span>
    );
  }
}

// wait for a whole bunch of things to be rendered
export class RenderGroup extends React.Component {
  private promises: Promise<void>[];

  ready: Promise<void>;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ready = Promise.all(this.promises).then(() => {});
  }

  render() {
    this.promises = [];

    return recursiveMap(this.props.children, node => {
      if (typeof node.type === "function" && node.type.prototype instanceof MJX) {
        const originalRef = node.ref;
        return React.cloneElement(node, {
          ref: (ref: MJX) => {
            if (!ref) return;
            this.promises.push(ref.ready);
            if (typeof originalRef === "function") {
              originalRef(ref);
            } else if (originalRef && typeof originalRef === "object") {
              originalRef.current = ref;
            }
          }
        });
      }

      return node;
    });
  }
}

// recursive React.Children.map
export function recursiveMap(
  children: React.ReactNode,
  fn: (child: React.ReactElement<any>) => React.ReactElement<any>
) {
  return React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement<any>(child)) {
      return child;
    }

    if ("children" in child.props) {
      child = React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: recursiveMap(child.props.children, fn)
      });
    }

    return fn(child);
  });
}
```

Here is an example which is close to real code. We use MathJax to create some `<input>`s inside 2D vectors. In my case this will integrate with a graphical display which is also interactive, so the values of the entries will be stored in the state of a parent component, and `Example` can both receive values from the parent and set those values. Since the `<input>`s do not exist until MathJax has finished typesetting, we have to manage them manually.

```js
interface Props {
  setParentValue: (i: number, value: number) => void;
  values: number[];
}

class Example extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  private div: HTMLDivElement;
  private inputs: HTMLInputElement[];
  private rg: RenderGroup;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.rg.ready.then(() => {
      this.inputs = this.div.querySelectorAll("input");
      for (let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; ++i) {
        this.inputs[i].addEventListener("change", e => this.props.setParentValue(i, e.target.value));
      }
    });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.inputs) {
      for (let i = 0; i < nextProps.values.length; ++i) {
        if (this.props.values[i] !== nextProps.values[i])
          this.inputs[i].value = nextProps.values[i];
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    // render only runs once, using initial values
    return (
      <div ref={ref => this.div = ref}>
        <RenderGroup ref={ref => this.rg = ref}>
          <MJX>{String.raw`
            \begin{bmatrix}
              \FormInput[4][matrix-entry][${this.props.values[0]}]{input1}\\
              \FormInput[4][matrix-entry][${this.props.values[1]}]{input2}
            \end{bmatrix}
          `}</MJX>

          <MJX>+</MJX>

          <MJX>{String.raw`
            \begin{bmatrix}
              \FormInput[4][matrix-entry][${this.props.values[2]}]{input3}\\
              \FormInput[4][matrix-entry][${this.props.values[3]}]{input4}
            \end{bmatrix}
          `}</MJX>

          <MJX>=</MJX>

          <MJX>{String.raw`
            \begin{bmatrix}
              ${this.props.values[0]+this.props.values[2]}\\
              ${this.props.values[1]+this.props.values[3]}
            \end{bmatrix}
          `}</MJX>
        </RenderGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my questions.

1. `RenderGroup` is brittle. For example I don't understand why I need to check `if (!ref)`; but if I omit that line, then `ref` will (for reasons I don't understand) become null on subsequent updates and cause an error. Intercepting the ref to grab the `ready` Promise also seems sketchy.
2. I'm slowly trying to migrate my class components to [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html); while this [isn't strictly necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components), according to the React team [it should be possible](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes). The problem is that function components don't have instances, so I don't see how to expose `.ready` to parent components like `Example`. I see there is a [`useImperativeHandle`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook for this scenario, but that seems to depend on ultimately having a ref to an HTML component. I guess in the case of `MJX` I could put a ref on the `<span>`, but this wouldn't work for `RenderGroup`.
3. Managing the inputs imperatively is painful and error-prone. Is there any way to get some of React's declarative goodness back?
4. Bonus: I haven't been able to figure out how to type `recursiveMap` properly; TypeScript gets angry at the `fn(child)` line. It would also be good to replace the any's with generics.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used MathJax, but in my experience, an "idiomatic React" way to handle the `resolveReady` stuff would probably be to pass a callback down through context that lets the children notify the parent when they're loading or ready. Example (with hooks!):

```
const LoadingContext = createContext(() => () => {});
const LoadingProvider = memo(LoadingContext.Provider);

function RenderGroup({ children }) {
  const [areChildrenReady, setAreChildrenReady] = useState(false);

  const nextChildIdRef = useRef(0);
  const unfinishedChildrenRef = useRef(new Set());
  const startLoading = useCallback(() => {
    const childId = nextChildIdRef.current++;
    unfinishedChildrenRef.current.add(childId);
    setAreChildrenReady(!!unfinishedChildrenRef.current.size);
    const finishLoading = () => {
      unfinishedChildrenRef.current.delete(childId);
      setAreChildrenReady(!!unfinishedChildrenRef.current.size);
    };
    return finishLoading;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (areChildrenReady) {
      // do whatever
    }
  }, [areChildrenReady]);

  return (
    <LoadingProvider value={startLoading}>
      {children}
    </LoadingProvider>
  );
}

function ChildComponent() {
  const startLoading = useContext(LoadingContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const finishLoading = startLoading();
    MathJaxReady
      .then(anotherPromise)
      .then(finishLoading);
  }, [startLoading]);
  return (
    // elements
  );
}
```